# Why shouldn't passwords be saved inside of appsettings.json in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: security, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

The [official documentation lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) the following practices for appsettings.json:

> - *Never store passwords or other sensitive data in configuration provider code or in plain text configuration files.*
> - Don't use production secrets in development or test environments.
> - Specify secrets outside of the project so that they can't be accidentally committed to a source code repository.

As far as I know the appsettings.json isn't served when you host the app on IIS and therefore can't be accessed from the web. We also host the source code ourselves (i.e. on our own servers). So as far as I can tell, the only real danger is when somebody manages to compromise the whole system and has actual access to the appsettings.json itself.

But are there other reasons for keeping sensitive data outside of appsettings.json? Are there other security aspects I'm overlooking?

I know there are several questions asking *how* to keep the appsettings.json secure, but not what the actual risks are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's many reasons, but the main one you've already mentioned:

- it's usually much, much easier to get access to source code, than it is to get to well-guarded secrets (e.g. Azure Vault)
- it's much easier to leak the secrets, possibly accidentally (via logs, or someone looking over your shoulder, or someone with access to the CI server)
- you won't typically *know* you've leaked them, as there's typically no or a lot less auditing than with proper systems for keeping secrets
- there's no way to limit the people that have access to specific secrets for specific environments
- personally, I also dislike having specifically *production* secrets near my development setup. If I run code as a developer, I want to be 100% sure I'll never be accidentally running against a production environment ("oops, I tested that mass-delete feature...vs production"). If the prod secrets are *just not there* then there's no mistake to make
- and probably many more reasons...

Basically, limiting the surface area for mistakes and security leaks will limit the chance for a problem, even if there is *currently* no reasonable combination of factors where a mistake or leak would happen.